# A 3 by 3 CSS Grid made of squares overflows outside container when using 'aspect-ratio: 1' to make cells square

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My aim is to create a 3 by 3 grid made of squares, which adjust to the size of the content, have corner numbers, and whose text content is centred both vertically and horizontally. After hours upon hours of attempting different ways to solve this issue, I'm left with a compromise between square cells and overflowing outside the container. I've tried different ways to achieve the 1:1 aspect ratio, but the methods haven't been compatible with my html + css. Height and width are deliberately not set to any specific values to enable the dynamic size of the cells and grid.

The first snippet shows a grid with squares, with a corner number. The only problem is that the content overflows. The grid container has to have position relative because of a label that goes next to the grid positioned with 'absolute', and which I could not include here.

The second snippet has the only difference that the 'aspect-ratio: 1' has been removed. The cells of the grid do not overflow the grid anymore, but they are not square either.

Is there a way to have square grid cells which adjust to content width and height without overflowing?

```css
.basic-text {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.fancy-card {
     border: 3px solid grey;
     border-radius: 15px;
     margin: 1em;
}
#output-card {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
}
#output-grid-container {
     margin: 1em;
     padding: 2em;
     position: relative;
     background-color: white;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
     gap: 20px;
}
.grid-square {
     position: relative;
     border: 2px solid grey;
     border-radius: 3px;
     padding: 1em;
     aspect-ratio: 1;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    /* Center horizontally */
     align-items: center;
    /* Center vertically */
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 150%;
}
p {
     white-space: pre;
     text-wrap: wrap;
}
.corner-rating-number {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0.1em;
     left: 0.3em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
select {
     height: 2em;
     width: 10em;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-card" id="output-card">
  <div id="output-grid-container">
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">7</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">8</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Pink</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">9</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">4</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">5</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Violet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">6</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">1</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">2</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">3</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Blue<br><br>Green</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.basic-text {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.fancy-card {
     border: 3px solid grey;
     border-radius: 15px;
     margin: 1em;
}
#output-card {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
}
#output-grid-container {
     margin: 1em;
     padding: 2em;
     position: relative;
     background-color: white;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
     gap: 20px;
}
.grid-square {
     position: relative;
     border: 2px solid grey;
     border-radius: 3px;
     padding: 1em;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    /* Center horizontally */
     align-items: center;
    /* Center vertically */
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 150%;
}
p {
     white-space: pre;
     text-wrap: wrap;
}
.corner-rating-number {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0.1em;
     left: 0.3em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
select {
     height: 2em;
     width: 10em;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-card" id="output-card">
  <div id="output-grid-container">
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">7</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">8</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Pink</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">9</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">4</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">5</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Violet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">6</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">1</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">2</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">3</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Blue<br><br>Green</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, remove the template-row declaration. Its a good place to start.

Comment: Nevertheless, I do not believe you can make ALL the squares the same size regardless of the content without javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D Please write an answer with your 'template-row' suggestion. Just removing 'grid-template-rows' messes up the grid, with gaps between rows. As to your second comment, the first of these snippets has squares of the same size making up the grid, and they expand with the size of the content in both vertical and horizontal directions. The only thing is that they overflow their container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by keeping `aspect-ratio: 1` on the squares, and checking what size the squares become. Then I set the column width explicitly to match the current size. This explicitly set size of the squares makes the outer div adjust to the inner size. Relevant code is in the snippet below.

If the page is supposed to update reactively, do this: when data for the grid is updated, set flag `squareDimensionsNeedUpdate` truthy. Before DOM update, if flag is truthy, `grid-template-columns` has to be set back to `repeat(3, 1fr)` in order for the squares to adjust to new contents. After the update, if flag is truthy, set flag falsy, and get and set the grid column width.

```js
let outputGridContainer = document.getElementById('output-grid-container');
let firstGridSquare = outputGridContainer.querySelector('.grid-square');
let firstGridSquareDimensions = firstGridSquare.getBoundingClientRect();
let firstGridSquareWidth = firstGridSquareDimensions.width;
outputGridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(3, ${firstGridSquareWidth}px)`;
```

```css
.basic-text {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.fancy-card {
     border: 3px solid grey;
     border-radius: 15px;
     margin: 1em;
}
#output-card {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
}
#output-grid-container {
     margin: 1em;
     padding: 2em;
     position: relative;
     background-color: white;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
     gap: 20px;
}
.grid-square {
     position: relative;
     border: 2px solid grey;
     border-radius: 3px;
     padding: 1em;
     aspect-ratio: 1;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    /* Center horizontally */
     align-items: center;
    /* Center vertically */
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 150%;
}
p {
     white-space: pre;
     text-wrap: wrap;
}
.corner-rating-number {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0.1em;
     left: 0.3em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
select {
     height: 2em;
     width: 10em;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-card" id="output-card">
  <div id="output-grid-container">
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">7</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">8</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Pink</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">9</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">4</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">5</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Violet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">6</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">1</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">2</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">3</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Blue<br><br>Green</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask "Is there a way to have square grid cells that adjust to the width and height of the content without overflowing?", but `aspect-ratio` is about the **width**-to-height ratio... So under normal conditions you you will not be able to get a square when the height is greater than the width.
So all that can be done that `.grid-square` does not stretch and are squares...The easiest way, is to add `overflow: hidden;` or `min-width: 0; minimum height: 0;`:

```css
.basic-text {
     font-size: larger;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.fancy-card {
     border: 3px solid grey;
     border-radius: 15px;
     margin: 1em;
}
#output-card {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
}
#output-grid-container {
     margin: 1em;
     padding: 2em;
     position: relative;
     background-color: white;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
     gap: 20px;
}
.grid-square {
     position: relative;
     border: 2px solid grey;
     border-radius: 3px;
     padding: 1em;
     aspect-ratio: 1;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    /* Center horizontally */
     align-items: center;
    /* Center vertically */
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 150%;
     
     overflow: hidden;
     /* min-width: 0; */
     /* min-height:0; */
}
p {
     white-space: pre;
     text-wrap: wrap;
}
.corner-rating-number {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0.1em;
     left: 0.3em;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
select {
     height: 2em;
     width: 10em;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-card" id="output-card">
  <div id="output-grid-container">
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">7</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">8</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Pink</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">9</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">4</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">5</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Violet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">6</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">1</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">2</span>
      <p class="basic-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-square">
      <span class="corner-rating-number basic-text">3</span>
      <p class="basic-text">Blue<br><br>Green</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's the first snippet in my post on CodePen: https://codepen.io/Joonatan-Partanen/pen/vYbBJwj. You can make the strings within the squares longer, or add more lines. The cells stay square. The only problem I have is the overflowing. Reading the MDN docs on aspect-ratio (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio), I don't see any reason why it wouldn't make the cells square, and evidently it works.

Comment: The reason is not in the `aspect-ratio`, but in the automatic calculation of the minimum sizes of the `grid` elements. The solution I gave you is to set `min-width` ≠ `auto` for elements. Or setting `overflow` ≠ `visible`.

Comment: The reason this is not a solution to my problem is that it removes the automatic scaling. I don't know beforehand what the content will be in the cells, so they need to scale automatically. Of course setting the sizes of the cells works, but it clashes with the requirements.

Comment: You said "So under normal conditions you you will not be able to get a square when the height is greater than the width." In the contrary: I am able to get squares if I use `aspect-ratio`, but it causes overflowing.